# Django templates avoid loop

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a project and I have a slight confusion.

The Django Template *index.html* has following code:

```
  <div class="carousel-item active">
      {% for i in products|slice:"0:"%}
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="card" style="width: 17rem;">
              <div class="card-body">
              {% for img in i.images.all %}
                  {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                  <img src={{img.img_url}} class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                  {% endif %}
               {% endfor %}

                <h6 class="card-title">{{i}}</h6>
                   {% for skus in i.skus.all %}
                                        {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                  <h6 class="card-price">{{skus.price}} {{skus.currency}}</h6>
                                        {% endif %}
               {% endfor %}
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

In this code, is there a way to eliminate the `{% for skus in i.skus.all %}`?

The all tag is getting all objects, but I am restricting the loop to run only one time through the *if* condition so that I can only get the first item.

Is there a way to eliminate the loops that have *.all* in them and restrict the statement to run only one time though any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by using either `with` tag to set a variable or direclty us as:

```
{% with skus=i.skus.first %}
    <h6 class="card-price">{{skus.price}} {{skus.currency}}</h6
{% endwith %}
```

or

```
<h6 class="card-price">{{i.skus.first.price}} {{i.skus.first.currency}}</h6
```

Comment: It isnt working

Comment: can you explain or add some more explanation to your question, how is do you expect to work.

Comment: Hey it worked. the problem was I had changed the name from i to prod_data so the above code wasn't working now I corrected it and it works. Also you hadn't put a closing > for h6 which was giving error. But overall Your answer was good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the [`first`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#first) queryset method:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <img src={{i.images.first().img_url}} class="card-img-top" alt="...">
</div>
```

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '().price' from 'i.skus.first().price'